# Vector Components - Superposition of Forces

Tags: linear-algebra, physics

[image]

I understand that by inspection of the given figure, $F_{1,x}$ (the *x*-component of $F_1$) must $< 0$, so $F_{1,x} = 250\color{red}{\cos{53^{\circ} }}$ can't be right. But I don't see how $F_{1,x} = (250)\color{red}{\cos{127^{\circ} }}$?

By definition, $F_x = F\cos\theta$ where $F$ is the hypotenuse of a right-angle triangle with $F_x, F_y$ as sides. Working with $127^{\circ}$ does not yield a right-angle triangle. Thank you very much!

---

@Maesumi: Thanks for your response. I understand that $127^{\circ}$ measured from the positive $x$-axis is the same as $-53^{\circ}$ measured from the negative $x$-axis. But knowing this, I still have my questions above.

---

@Maesumi: Thanks for your 2nd response. I understand reference angles but I don't see why $F_{1,x} = (250)\color{red}{\cos{127^{\circ} }} $ makes sense graphically.  From my picture, $\cos{127^{\circ}}$ can be found using Cosine Law, but it doesn't involve the pink line, $F_{1,x}$, which is what we want.

Comment: I am guessing that confusion is about measurement of angles in standard position. $F_{1x}=250 \cos127$ where $127$ is measured from positive side of $x$ axis. It looks like you need to take a look at beginning of section on "arbitrary angles" in a trig book.

Comment: In general trig functions are defined through coordinates of a point on the terminal side of the angle. If such a point is $(x,y)$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then $\cos\theta= x/r$. The language of adjacent, opposite, hypotenuse, is then no longer used, as you say these notions are only for acute angles and right triangles.

Comment: @Maesumi: Thanks for your response, in light of which I've updated my post. I'm still confused, though.

Comment: If you measure the angle $\theta'$ from negative side of $x$ axis then you should use $F_x=-F\cos \theta'$. This angle is called the reference angle and one uses the supplementary angle identity  $\cos \theta'=-\cos \theta$ whenever $\theta'=180-\theta$.

Comment: @Maesumi: Thanks for your second response. Unfortunately, I still don't understand the given solution fully so I've updated my post. My problem doesn't seem to be with reference angles, which I understand.

Comment: i'm skeptical as to why you are using law of cosines. it's hard to discuss without exchanging drawings. Feel free to use $F_{1,x}=-250\cos(53^\circ)$. You can draw a right triangle in a straightforward way. Notice Maesumi's mention of "arbitrary angles", which seems to be an indication I am no better at elucidating.

Comment: here is the first thing i could find. http://www.intmath.com/trigonometric-functions/5-signs-of-trigonometric-functions.php. I think it may be an odd thing that few of us have thought carefully about, it's subtle, and you may have to accept like many of us do. I think the link will help give context to Maesumi's second comment.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Maesumi: Your second response is the answer precisely. Would you mind posting it as an official Answer below? Then I can pick it and close this question.

Comment: @Maesumi: Sorry, I actually meant your third response, so I edited your answer accordingly. I hope that this is fine with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you measure the angle $\theta′ = 180 - θ$ from negative side of $x$-axis then you should use

$$F_x=−F\cosθ′=F\cos(180 - θ).$$ 
This angle is called the reference angle and one uses the supplementary angle identity 
$$ \cos θ′= \cos(180 - θ) = -\cosθ $$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with abstract vector notation, then we will use rectangular and polar coordinates as convenient.

In vector notation, we have $F_{net}=\sum F_i=F_1+F_2+F_3$.

Since addition of vectors works better in rectangular coordinates, and the data is give to us in polar coordinates, that directs us to our first step.

$F_{net}=F_{net,x}+F_{net,y}$. Let's work on the $x$ component first.

$F_{net,x}=\sum F_{i,x}=250\cos(127)+50+0\approx-100$.

$F_{net,y}=\sum F_{i,y}=250\sin(127)+0-120\approx 80$.

At this point, we have the $x$ and $y$ components of $F_{net}$, and we may now tackle the problem of converting $F_{net}$ to polar coordinates.